# passing a coderef to sort() problems

Tags: perl, coderef

Using the following pieces of code, I get wildly different results.

```
$val{"ENOTE"} = 05;
$val{"WATCH"} = 10;

my %sortFunc = ();

my $sortFunc = sub {
    my ($va, $vb);

    $va = $val{$$a{"etype"} . ":" . $$a{"emsg"}} // $val{$$a{"etype"}};
    $vb = $val{$$b{"etype"} . ":" . $$b{"emsg"}} // $val{$$b{"etype"}};

    #    printf("$$a{etype} gets $va\n");

    $$a{"year"} <=> $$b{"year"}
    || $$a{"month"} <=> $$b{"month"}
    || $$a{"day"} <=> $$b{"day"}
    || $$a{"sym"} cmp $$b{"sym"}
    || $va <=> $vb;
};

$sortFunc{"date"} = sub {
    my ($va, $vb);

    $va = $val{$$a{"etype"} . ":" . $$a{"emsg"}} // $val{$$a{"etype"}};
    $vb = $val{$$b{"etype"} . ":" . $$b{"emsg"}} // $val{$$b{"etype"}};

    #    printf("$$a{etype} gets $va\n");

    $$a{"year"} <=> $$b{"year"}
    || $$a{"month"} <=> $$b{"month"}
    || $$a{"day"} <=> $$b{"day"}
    || $$a{"sym"} cmp $$b{"sym"}
    || $va <=> $vb;
};
```

When I call them, I get wildly different results.

```
@newsortrec = sort $sortFunc (@$rec);
@newsortrec = sort {$sortFunc{"date"}} (@$rec);
```

The call to `$sortFunc` works as I'd expect, and I have verified its output.  The output from `{$sortFunc{"date"}}` is really odd.  It's not gibberish like you'd expect if it had gotten bad data or ran bad code.  It's just sorted in the wrong order.  It's changed, and it's "sorted", but in a really weird way.

Is there something about the mysterious `$a` and `$b` that's giving me grief?

The fact that they are (foolishly) named `$sortFunc` shouldn't be a concern, should it?  At least as far as **perl** is concerned.

Is there something different about the scoping rules for `$a` and `$b`?

I've `diff`ed the code, so I know that it's the same.

Any hints/clues?  I'm trying to move the code into the hash (where it runs... strangely).

Thanks.

-Erik

Comment: I left a piece of the code out.  `$va` and `$vb` are numeric.  `$val{"ENOTE"} = 05;`, for example.  Sorry for the confusion. -E

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the `sort BLOCK LIST` calling convention, the block should return a value that indicates how `$a` compares to `$b`. However, your sort compare block returns a code ref (`$sortFunc{"date"}`). You might as well have used

```
 sort { 1 } @$rec;
```

Replace

```
 sort { $sortFunc{date} } @$rec;
```

with

```
 sort { $sortFunc{date}->() } @$rec;
```

Comment: OK.  That worked.  Why didn't `$sortFunc`, need the same treatment?  And why didn't `$sortFunc{date}` (without the BLOCK parens) work (it didn't even run)?  And just for yuks, what "type" is a BLOCK?  a coderef works sometimes, it seems.  In any case, your changes work, and many thanks to you.  -Erik

Comment: Is it because `$sortFunc` was in the symbol table as a coderef, whereas the value of a hash usually isn't in the symbol table at all?

Comment: Because it doesn't follow the `sort BLOCK LIST` calling convention. For example, `sort { $sortFunc } ...` would give you the same result as `sort { $sortFunc{date} } ...`. `sort $sortFunc ...` does not match any of the documented calling conventions, but works as `sort SUBNAME LIST`.

Comment: Re "*And just for yuks, what "type" is a BLOCK?*", A block is a syntactical element of the form "`{ STATEMENTS }`"